# What are some examples of out of bound channels that work over the Internet in practice?

Tags: rsa, public-key, pgp, pki, verifiability

If I want to verify a public key (be it RSA, PGP, etc.) with another client over the Internet only, what are some viable out-of-bound channels for verification? Which channels have been used in practice and worked?